# Search if two strings both in separate columns exist in one row in excel?

Tags: excel, search

How can I use the find function to see if two strings exist in excel?

EX:

```
row/column  A        B       C     D
       1    fly     cat    dog    fish
       2    cat    pig    horse   dog
       3    zebra  pig     cat    elephant
```

I want to search what rows both contains cat and dog. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can give you a formula without using the find function. Will that work? Does case matter?

Comment: @pnuts - surely "complex" is a subjective term - what's complex for me might not be for you or vice versa - in my view that makes the term "complex formula development" not particularly useful, especially as those asking, normally by definition, don't know the answer!

Answer (score 2):

How about use `AND`,`COUNTIF` function together:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"cat"),COUNTIF(A1:D1,"dog"))
```

If the row contains both `cat` and `dog`,it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: This is actually the best way to write the formula.

Comment: Right. When I wrote the comment here, I was more just referring to how overly complicated my formula is and how simple this formula is.

Comment: @pnuts That is exactly what I did (separate search terms out) in my answer :)

Comment: It was to convert a geeky number (0/1/2) into text for readability and potentially filtering

Comment: How so? `COUNTIF` will return 0 if the criteria is not found.  BTW - anchoring the columns was to assist with propagating the formula and not getting themselves into trouble.

Comment: Ok - I accept anchoring wasn't absolutely necessary.  I also get you can produce TRUE/FALSE like that - both work equally well - but using the IF provides a more user-friendly output.

Answer (score 1):

If the formula returns a 1, the row contains both cat and dog. If it returns 0, at least one is missing from the row:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(A1:D1="cat"))*MAX(--(A1:D1="dog")))
```

Comment: @rwilson This doesn't seem to work. Even when I edit it for a bigger file that A:D. It just always returns 0.

Comment: The formula didn't work when used on the sample above? The formula only looks for an exact match. If a row contains the word "dogs", searching for "dog" with this formula won't return a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to run a formula on each line, then you could copy this down and check for a value of "2".

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A3:$D3,"cat")>0,COUNTIF($A3:$D3,"dog")>0),"Found them","")
```

You could replace the literals for a cell reference so that you can easily change out your search words.  Maybe something like this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A3:$D3,$F$1)>0,COUNTIF($A3:$D3,$G$1)>0),"Found them","")
```

Comment: But =2 potentially gives some false positives (what if there are 2 dogs) or the opposite (what if there are 2 dogs and 1 cat?)

Comment: Well spotted @barryhoudini!  I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really love `find` function,though it seemed longer.

```
=AND(FIND("cat",CONCATENATE(A1,"|",B1,"|",C1,"|",D1)),FIND("dog",CONCATENATE(A1,"|",B1,"|",C1,"|",D1)))
```

Separator `|`  is important!

`cat` + `dog` = `catdog`

`ca` + `tdog` = `catdog`

But add separator `|`(or other) will not:

`cat` + `|`+ `dog` = `cat|dog`

`ca` +  `|` + `tdog`= `ca|tdog`

Note that `find` is case-sensitive.
If not case-sensitive you can use `search` function.